# c++ searching villages pased

Tags: c++, matrix, path

---

### We want to have the village that this person has passed to get from start to the end.

1/the user should enter the number of villages and translate the path to a matrix

[image]
we have a matrix dynamic allocation

`a b c d e f` are the villages
if there is a bridge between two villages `1` and if not `0`

Note: The user is the one who fill the matrix and the leters not included

*************.**************************************************************************************************
What I chose to do but I think that we can use recursive too

******************the loop********************

The loop start line by line
If it gets a `0` then `i++` else if it get `1` it print the location and then it jump to other line

Example 1:

It start from `a[0][0]` to `b[0][1]` then jump the pointer jump to `b[1][0]` and 
we set `b` to `0` in the two cases. So we dont have a repetition of the same case

In the previous example it should print the Coordinates of `a and b` and `c and d`

In example 2 it should print the Coordinates  of `a c b d f` here is my try

```
void permut(int *x, int *y)
{
    int c;
    c = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = c;
}

main()
{   
    int x, y;

//creation
    cout << "donner la talle de matrice (ligne puis colone) : \n";
    cin >> x >> y;
    int **grid = new int *[y];
    for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i)
    {   
        grid[i] = new int[x];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {   
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {   
            cout << "t[" << i << "][" << j << "] : ";
            cin >> grid[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {   
        cout << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {   
            cout << grid[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";

    do
    {   
        int i , j;
        if (grid[i][j] == 1)
        {   
            cout << i << "  " << j << "\n";
            permut(&i, &j);
            grid[i][j] = 0;
            grid[j][j] = 0;
            continue;
        }
        else if (grid[i][j] == 0)
        {   
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        break;

    }while (1);

//delete

    for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i)
    {   
        delete[] grid[i];
    }

    delete[] grid;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to learn about [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) or some other way to format your code. This is *not* pleasant to read.

Comment: Why are you using manual memory management (`delete[]` etc) in 2018? We have containers. We have smart pointers. Don't write C++ like it's 1998 - please. Embrace C++17 (or *at least* C++11).

Comment: Why does your `permut` function exist? Don't you just want `std::swap`?

Comment: Modern C++ also has this neat thing called range-based for loops - and *`algorithms`*.

Comment: `main()` is straight-up wrong. `main` returns `int` - *always*. You don't even have a *wrong* `void` return value there.

Comment: `while (1)` - C++ is not C. We have expressive things like `true` and `false` for boolean values. We don't have to rely on integers.

Comment: `int **grid = new int *[y];` - No. Just no.

Comment: allocation dynamique int **grid = new int *[y];

Comment: Repeating it doesn't help. It's still horrible code that should not be written. Ever heard of `std::vector`?

Comment: [Here is a reasonable, safe, and easy-to-use matrix to use instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  do
{
    if (tab[i][j] == 1)
    {
        cout << "village (" << i << ") then " << endl;
        swap(i, j);
        tab[i][j] = 0;
        tab[j][i] = 0;
    }
    else if (tab[i][j] == 0)
    {
        i++;}
    } while (i != breaki || j != breakj);
cout << "your are arrived !!\n";
```